# Nested template_file in terraform

Tags: json, bash, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have two template files in terraform.

The first template file looks like this:

```
script.sh.tpl
------------------
echo "some_content" > config.json
consul --config config.json
```

The second template file needs to take the content of first template file. Here is my second template file:

```
task-definition.json.tpl
----------------------
[
      ...
      "command":[${consul_script}]
      "image": "some_docker_image:latest",
      "name": "test-app"
    }
]
```

here is what main.tf looks like:

```
main.tf
-----------------------
data "template_file" "task_definition_template" {
  template = file("task-definition.json.tpl")
  vars = {
    consul_script = data.template_file.consul_script.rendered
  }
}

data "template_file" "consul_script" {
  template = file("script.sh.tpl")
  vars = {
    var1 = "test"
  }
}
```

I tried using this, but it's giving me error like this:

> ECS Task Definition is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character '\n' in string literal terraform

How can I get rid of this issue and successfully pass the first .tpl in to the second template file?

Comment: Can you show the wider context for the error? Is it happening when rendering the template or when being used by the `aws_ecs_task_defintion` resource? Ideally the code in your question should form a [mcve] that can be ran to reproduce your exact error.

Comment: Hi, the context is that I am passing a template file as input variable to the another tempate file.

Comment: I mean show the surrounding lines to the error which shows where the error is occurring. If you could also edit your question so that the code forms a [mcve] then that would also help people understand your issue and be able to help you.

Comment: It's throwing error in the task-definition.json.tpl. The exact error was: ECS Task Definition  is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character '\n' in string literal terraform

Comment: Updated the question as well. the ${consul_script} part inside task-definition.json.tpl is giving the issue.

Comment: Then your issue is different. If you output the rendered template it is fine but the issue is that the `commands` parameter for an ECS task definition takes a list of single word strings similar to the [exec form of CMD in a Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd). Also see the [AWS docs for ECS task definition parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html)

Comment: But, when I pass the command in the task-definition.json.tpl like this: 
"command":["echo "some_content" > config.json\nconsul --config config.json"], it works perfectly fine.

Comment: This seems like a typical sort of problem that results when trying to generate JSON using string templating. You can see a different way to this, which ensures that the result will always be valid JSON, in the Terraform docs section [Generating JSON or YAML from a template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template).